# ASP.NET MVC 5 error - Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-5

I am testing some simple reflection to new up types that implement an interface inside a brand new ASP.NET MVC web application targeting .NET 4.5. I am getting the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

**Scenario**

I have created a brand new ASP.NET MVC application on .NET 4.5. I am using this version for backwards compatibility. I add the following code to a controller. The controller or end point does not matter. So just for testing I put the code in `HomeController`'s `About` method.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        try
        {
            var testInterfaceType = typeof(ITest);
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => !p.IsAbstract && !p.IsInterface && testInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(p));

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var instance = (ITest)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                instance.Execute();
            }
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            var loaderExceptions = e.LoaderExceptions;
            // I get 5 of these LoaderExceptions, all the same. e.g 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces . . .'
        }

        return View();
    }
```

`ITest` is a simple interface as follows that lives inside the ASP.NET MVC app project.

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Execute();
}
```

And I have implemented one simple instance of it thus (again this instance lives inside the ASP.NET MVC app project)

```
public class Test1 : ITest
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from test 1");
    }
}
```

The solution builds and runs perfectly. The error is thrown once I hit the code in `HomeController` `About` method.  Please bear in mind I have not added any references to the new boiler plated ASP.NET MVC app. I have not added and Nuget packages. There is no mention of Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces as a string in any solution wide search. There are no files anywhere within the solution whose names contains 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces'. There are no references to any project whose name contains 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces'.

As far as I know, Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces is pure a .NET Standard/Core animal so why am I seeing this error in ASP.NET MVC 5 / .NET 4.5?

I'd appreciate any help. Many thanks.

Comment: I'd close as not replicable. Created a brand new .NET 4.5 MVC app in VS 2022. Added your code. Run. No exception.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - What versions of .Net Framework have you installed? Have you .Net 6 or .Net 7?  I've a feeling these could be the culprits.

Comment: Most of them. 6 and 7 too.